# How do we distinguish "walks" or "paths"?

Tags: graph-theory, definition

For example, let $G(V,E)$ be a graph such that $V=\{v_1,v_2\}$ and $E=\{(v_1,v_2)\}$. And let $s_1:\{1,2\}\rightarrow V$ be a walk such that $s_1(1)=v_1$ and $s_1(2)=v_2$. And let $s_2:\{3,4\}\rightarrow V$ be a walk such that $s_2(3)=v_1$ and $s_2(4)=v_2$.

Then $s_1\neq s_2$ since $\{1,2\}\neq \{3,4\}$. However, we know that *the number of walks of length 1* from $v_1$ to $v_2$ is 1. (?)

How do we define walks? Do we define *walk* as  a function from a *von-Neumann ordinal* ? Or is it just an identity map? (That is, $s(v_i)=v_i$)

Comment: If you want to get this pedantic, then you should define two walks to be isomorphic if there's a bijection between their index sets that intertwines the corresponding function to the set of vertices and count isomorphism classes of walks. But this is too pedantic for my tastes. A walk is an ordered sequence of vertices connected by edges. It doesn't matter what set you use to index it.

Comment: A walk is a sequence of vertices where adjacent vertices are, well, adjacent. Do you think there is more than one two-element sequence that begins with $v_1$ and ends with $v_2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will suit your set-theoretic tastes. The set of walks of length $n$ is a subset of $V^n$, namely it is the subset consisting of $n$-tuples $(v_1, ... v_n)$ such that $(v_i, v_{i+1}) \in E$ for all $i$. When we count walks we are computing the cardinality of this subset.